# How to save a file being streamed using Real Time Streaming Protocol?

Tags: video, video-streaming

I want to save an mp4 video file which is being streamed using [`rtsp://`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol).

I have tried to save it using `ffmpeg`, but the result I got was with numerous mistakes.
I tried VLC also, but the video and audio were unsynchcronised.
'rtmpdump' does not work neither.

For example, I want to save the following video being streamed using this protocol:

```
rtsp://a1966.v1252936.c125293.g.vq.akamaistream.net/7/1966/125293/v0001/mp4.od.origin.zdf.de.gl-systemhaus.de/dach/zdf/13/12/131231_buniatishvili_kuk_1456k_p13v11.mp4
```

How may I achieve the same?

Comment: it is not spam quiestion

Comment: i'm trying to save this video, but i can not unfortenately. I have tried to save it with ffmpeg, but the result I got was with numerous mistakes

Comment: You know, I have read a bunch of answers to "how could i save a rtsp stream video?" , but it did not work for this particular example

Comment: Dumindu Mahawela, i tried, i got RTMPDump v2.4
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
WARNING: Unknown protocol!

WARNING: You haven't specified an output file (-o filename), using stdout
Connecting ...
ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 110 (Connection timed out)

Comment: Is it legal to save this video?

Comment: No copy rights infomation is found.

Comment: @incel: Since you have already tried out a couple of things, please [edit] the question and incorporate whatever you have tried and what have been the results... That way, neither we would have to repeat the same stuff again nor would you have to wait to hear out the same stuff you have already tried; and you would have chances of receiving better, faster and accurate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Open the **VLC media player**.

Go to the :

`Media`> `Convert/Save..`

Here Paste the URL.

Then click on the `Convert/Save` button.

You can also save it with command line:

```
vlc [STREAM URL] --sout=file/ps:[FILE NAME].MP4
```

Tt should be :

```
vlc rtsp://a1966.v1252936.c125293.g.vq.akamaistream.net/7/1966/125293/v0001/mp4.od.origin.zdf.de.gl-systemhaus.de/dach/zdf/13/12/131231_buniatishvili_kuk_1456k_p13v11.mp4 --sout=file/ps:aa.mpg
```

Comment: I have tried it, the result had error (for example, audio and video were unsynchronised)

Comment: If So first play it by `media`> ` Network stream` and paste url and click on `play`. then while it is playing, go to `media`> `Convert/Save..` and do above.

Comment: ok, I will try it, but I am not sure it will help. But anyway thank You for your help!

Comment: I tried. I can download it. May be a problem in your VLC. Also try with `rtmpsuck [URL]`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Media` → `Open Network Stream`, paste your RSTP link and instead of `Play` pick `Stream` menu item. Choose a `File` as destination, add a filename. Check `Display locally`, if you want your stream to be played during recording (otherwise a black screen will be "played"). Uncheck `Activate Transcoding`, if you need to capture original stream without any transcoding (which you probably do).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is by using ffmpeg, like this:

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://source_url_full_file_name  -acodec copy  -vcodec copy local_target_file_name.mp4

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292235/997940))